# Outlook for Mac 15.40 broke our Angular add-in

Tags: angularjs, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

We have a side-loaded Outlook add-in written in AngularJS 1.5 that uses hash path parameters, for example:

```
https://our.domain.com/ouraddin/index.html?brand=x#/settings
```

After updating Outlook 2016 for Mac to version 15.40 the add-in stopped working. We are getting an error that only occurs if $routeParams.id is not set.

Is anyone else seeing the same problem with 15.40? Everything was working fine in Outlook 2016 for Mac before the update.

Update: It looks like Outlook 2016 for Mac 15.40 is now messing up the URLs from the add-in manifest by encoding the # as %23. The URL above becomes:

```
https://our.domain.com/ouraddin/index.html?brand=x&_hostInfo=Outlook$Mac$16.01$en-US%23/settings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been fixed. It will reflect in a future update, in Build 15.40 (171018) and above.

Comment: Thanks @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility. Do you have a rough eta for that build?

Comment: we currently have 15.40 (171108) installed and the problem occurs. 171108 seems higher than 171018. Was the problem not fixed? Is the build number you gave incorrect?

Comment: That last comment was directed at @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility but somehow the name reference was removed. Can you please confirm the expected fix version number?

Comment: I installed Outlook for Mac 15.41 (171205) and the problem still occurs. @Mac_Outlook_Extensibilty what happened to the fix?

Comment: Are you signed up for the Insider builds? If not, this fix has not gone out to external users yet, and is expected to be available in a month or so.

Comment: As of update 16.9 (180116) the problem is still there. @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility when can we expect the fix?

Comment: I signed up for insider updates and tried 16.10 (180114) and still it does not work. @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility this is a serious issue.